# Get state of another reducer with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to know if it's possible, in a reducer, to get state of another reducer. I'm using react-redux :

```
import * as reducers from "./client/components/reducers";
const reducer = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing : routerReducer,
});

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  DevTools.instrument()
);
```

I have two reducers : wallets and operations.
When I add/update an operation, I want to calculate the total of my wallet and save it in my wallets reducer.

Here are my wallets reducer :

```
import { INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, UPDATE_ALL, SET_TOTAL } from "./wallets.constants";
import { INSERT as INSERT_OPERATION, UPDATE as UPDATE_OPERATION, DELETE as DELETE_OPERATION } from "../operations/operations.constants";

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  const result = Object.assign({}, state);
  if (action.wallet && !action.wallet.uuid) {
    return state;
  }
  switch(action.type) {
    case INSERT :
    case UPDATE :
    case DELETE :
      result[action.wallet.uuid] = action.wallet;
      return result;
    case INSERT_OPERATION :
    case UPDATE_OPERATION :
    case DELETE_OPERATION :
      // Here I want to calculate total of operations in this wallet
      return result;
    default : return state
  } 
}
```

I though to increment my total for each Insert instead of re-calculate all the total each time but if it's an Update it's not possible because I need to decrement old value that I don't have here.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

It's best to try and keep your state tree as normalized as possible - it helps to think about it almost as a relational database. If you do this it means issues I think you're having here are simplified. So (if I understand your requirement correctly) you can save your add/update/etc operations in the state and calculate the total 'on the fly' rather than hold it in state (as you should be able to derive it from the collection of operations?).

Helper functions that can be used to interpret the normalized data stored in state are called *selectors* in Redux. Have a look here:

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html